# On Exponential Collatz Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, collatz-conjecture

I was studying the collatz conjecture and managed to show that the problem is equivalent the union of a set of conjectures (well uncountably many conjectures, one for each $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ ).

One such conjecture is, consider the function given by:

$$ f(x) = 2\left( 2x+ \frac{1}{5} \right) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{6^k} \frac{e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}e^{-\frac{4\pi ix}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}}{1-e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}e^{-\frac{4\pi ix}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}} \right]  $$

The conjecture is that 
$$ f(n) = f(1) \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

This looks like a reasonably well behaved object, its some complex exponentials, in a geometric series, with nested 6^th roots. Is there a way to prove this without assuming Collatz?

A starting point, would be to break the conjecture into a statement for each natural number, and just trying to show that (in this case x = 1, x= 2)

### $$ \frac{22}{5}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{6^k} \frac{e^{-\frac{6\pi i}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}}{1-e^{-\frac{6\pi i}{5}\frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}} \right]  = 
 \frac{42}{5} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{6^k} \frac{e^{-2\pi i \frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}}{1-e^{-2 \pi i \frac{6^{k}-1}{6^k}}} \right]  $$

Some findings from Wolfram Alpha, the RHS is equal to 0 from $k = 1 ... 155$ (I think that must be some kind of bug), and from $156$ onwards the sum isn't defined, (which seems very counterintuitive, and unlikely)

Comment: .... the sum in the RHS doesn't converge

Comment: Wait I have omitted a (-1) power. I am sorry @mercio it is now corrected

Comment: still, I don't believe the terms inside converge to $0$

Comment: Hmm. Let me look into it carefully, is tricky becuse the exponentials are quickly reaching $\frac{1}{0}$ while the cofficients themselves are reaching 0 exponentially fast.

Comment: @mercio I'm going to play around a bit more, but it seems wolfram alpha doesn't find it clear whether it will or won't converge https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(-1%2F6)%5E(k%2B1)+e%5E(-2*pi*i+*+(6%5Ek+-1)%2F(6%5Ek))+%2F+(1+-+e%5E(-2*pi*i+*+(6%5Ek+-1)%2F6%5Ek))++from+1+to+infinity

Comment: @mercio for some reason Wolfram, thinks the infinite sum is inconclusive but finite truncations are undefined (which makes no sense), either way if I evaluate it for large number of terms it seems to converge to something https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+((-1%2F6)%5E(k%2B1)+e%5E(-2*pi*i+*+(6%5Ek+-1)%2F(6%5Ek))+%2F+(1+-+e%5E(-2*pi*i+*+(6%5Ek+-1)%2F6%5Ek)))++from+1+to+101

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use $e^a e^b = e^{a+b}$ and factor some stuff in the exponents ?

Comment: Just substitution, yea that can be cleaned up

Comment: How do you get these statements from the Collatz conjecture?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Basically they arise from non trivial solutions to functional equations that obey the collatz recursion. This particular one comes as a non trivial solution to $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} ( 1- e^{i\pi x} ) f(3x + 1) + \frac{1}{2} (1 - e^{i \pi x} ) f \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) $. Observe that for integer $x$ if $x$ is odd then $f(x) = f(3x+1)$ and if $x$ is even then $f(x) = f \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) $ . So these functions are constant on sets of natural numbers that limit to the same collatz cycles. If all such functions are constant on all natural numbers, then it easily follows

Comment: @frogeyedpeas does your formulation not mean that these will be constant only if some integer converges to a cycle of order 1 (measured in odd numbers)? In other words, if some cycle included multiple odd numbers would this method apply?

Comment: @RobertFrost the functional equation would recurse. Say there are multiple odd numbers, then f(x) = f(3x+1) = f((3x+1)/2) = (let’s assume x is odd) f(3(3x+1)/2+1) (etc...). Spiraling off indefinitely. But if somewhere along the way that sequence is equal to 1 in the argument. Then it must be the case that f(x) = f(1). A simpler example is to consider f(x) = 1 + f(x-1) = 2 + f(x-2) ... = k + f(x-k) for every integer k.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas does that allow for multiple divisions of two in-between any given pair of 3x+1, or just a single division by two?

Comment: Multiple, if the value of X is even, then $e^(2*pi*i X) $will be 1, so we will end up with f(x) = f(x/2). If x/2 is even then it follows that f(x) = f(x/2) = f(x/4) by the same argument

Comment: This descends down till it stops being even